# How to install specified framework in Teamcity server as a build step

Tags: .net-core, teamcity

I have dotnet project built using dotnetcore v2.0 which was working fine in Teamcity pipeline.

I have updated the project to use dotnetcore v3.0 and re-run the Teamcity build.

now I am getting the error

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version

```
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
 - The following frameworks were found:
     1.0.3 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
     2.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
     2.0.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
     2.2.3 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
     5.0.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

How to install the dotnetcore v3.0 in the build step.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure TeamCity will do it for you.  You will need to go install it on the build agent.